# Ocaml and eclipse with ocalIDE get a syntaxe error on #use command

Tags: eclipse, ocaml

I use ocalIDE as ocaml plugin in eclipse but on every #use foo line I got a

```
syntax error: unexpected token "#".
```

If I run this exact file in the toplevel windows it's working well, but I can't use the plugin tool (type info and auto-complete mainly) as it cannot compile my file.

Have you got any Idea why it cannot compile? I've got myFile.byte in the project parameter and without the #use line it's compile (well once I remove all what cannot work as the 'use' file isn't included...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`#use` and other `#`-directives are not part of the Ocaml language, they are instructions specifically for the [toplevel](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual023.html). Since you can't use them in Ocaml source code, it's not surprising that tools designed to work on Ocaml source code won't cope with them.

To use a function (or type, etc.) from a [module](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual004.html#toc13), just write `Modulename.function` (e.g. `List.hd [1; 2]`). If you want to use functions from a module without having to repeat the module name, use the [`open` keyword](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual019.html#@manual.kwd170) (e.g. `open Unix`).

Comment: well that's quite understandable but it doesn't resolve my probleme as I cannot use the function in my second file called utiles.ml that contain a module called Utiles end I've got the open Utiles;; in my code but still OcalIDE cannot compile it, is there something I forgot?

Comment: Did you write an interface (`.mli`) for the first module? Did you compile it? (I don't know OcalIDE, maybe it's supposed to do this automatically.) If you haven't written an interface, you'll need to compile the source of the first implementation (but writing an interface is recommended). If this comment doesn't help, add to your question a small, complete piece of code that you expected to work, and copy-paste the complete error message when you try to compile.

Comment: After doing some research with what you just told me I found that our Utiles module is define in it's ml file like this:
    module Utiles =
    struct ... end;;
which it shouldn't be as this is a File I cannot change I've got to do Utiles.Utiles.fonction so that it work.
I'm I right I find it strange that it's need to be like that if we want to run it in toplevel but once compile the same code cannot work?

Comment: @djo0012: It's certainly unusual to have `module Utiles` in a file called `utiles.ml` (the file itself creates a module called `Utiles`). If you do `#use "utiles.ml";;`, that includes the file verbatim; `open Utiles` would be (roughly) equivalent, and in either case you still need `Utiles.foo` to access `foo` from the module. I don't understand your last sentence, try using simpler grammar.

Comment: you answer the question thanks, I'll have to check with the writer of the Utiles module. Thanks again.